# Drupal taxonomy popular list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

There are about 70 categories in Drupal 7 with taxonomy. I would like to get list 20 of the most popular(most used), sorted from most popular to the least placed in block.

```
Dogs (200 Entries)
Cats (120 Entries) 
..
```

Is there a module that has this functionality, or how would you get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tagadelic](http://drupal.org/project/tagadelic) module.

With a bit of CSS you can change the modules' display to not render popular tags larger then less popular tags.

And with a simple theme-override you can add the amount (200) of usage to the output too.

Comment: And the Drupal7 version is not yet released on Drupal.org, but lives on github: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=github+tagadelic